# Adding my own easing functions to javaScript library (Paper.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I want to extend the Paper.js library (https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js) to add my own easing functions. The full source code of the library is here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.15/paper-full.js.

However, the relevant part is this:

```
var Tween = Base.extend(Emitter, {
    _class: 'Tween',

    statics: {
        easings: new Base({
            linear: function(t) {
                return t;
            },

            easeInQuad: function(t) {
                return t * t;
            }
        })
    },
// More code
```

I know I can create a local copy of the entire source code and make the changes to the file locally to add my own custom easing functions. However, I wanted to know if there is any way to add my own easing functions without changing the original library and making changes to the other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even have to do this because Paper.js accepts custom easing functions.
So you simply have to pass your custom easing function when creating the `Tween`.
Here's a simple [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/VVDBDoIwDP2VZRcgIYSYeJlHfsBEb+JhbkUWZmdGkRjCv8swoLxTX99rX9OBo3wAF/zUAKmap1w5HThCz46S6qwwXlmIh9KXyCYoQAIv2MtAn31JumheatO1gu3ztVUZawtn3TQRvcFa10dBGpOMegA8u3hxDhuvBx2xcV2zxgfozksyDgXb5fkvKgBka/AuWNWhCpaYku3sfCZQ55HR4V8YFzIXyaxN77h5kM3TGaSWi8t1/AA=) demonstrating this.

```js
new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'yellow'
}).tweenTo(
    { fillColor: 'red' },
    {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: function(t) {
            return t;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Sasensi. This works. :). Is it possible to pass a function name to the easing parameter instead of defining it here? I tried `easing: easeOutBounce(t)` with easeOutBOunce(t) defined somewhere else but got errors.

Comment: Sketch link: http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/hZLBTsMwDIZfxeplLYzQFbpBYRf2ACCBtAPjkLUejRoSlLpUaOq7k2y0ox3SLEVK/P/+ZDneeop/oJd4zwVSmntjL9WZe28qlZLQCpCX+FjRg7YJ9CmA7cqsFNhItSoJ1ATmMGPxNIrv+krmlIjN9vlWExvwCe5hApfW8QfnwiBVRjnmGZA7HbIBlCV21dGpauu6mMOExb9GxzuHsO3mP2TnPQGNWDSk3l4dc09SpseYm+seyF2adngKa3jilLOFMKlE//APqAhNAl8Ca7Z/jFvN8ExUZQJx2KU2QsqFltpWjL5RSl2POq0kowts1bXkaTEUlyKjPIFo11vAqEZUL9pvTduBLYSmA/QmklWGuwVznvDQnQu7ckK9J0er15tLsBuTXdi1QV58aqGo9JLXt+YH

Comment: The error says `t` is not defined.

Comment: You are calling the function before passing it, just pass the function itself: `easing: easeOutBounce`